Ring whose finitely generated ideals are principal
The boolean ring $\prod_{n\in N} (Z/2Z)$ is an example of rings that verifie two properties

every finitely generated ideals are principal
there exits ideals that are not principal.

My question : is it possible to find an integral domain that has the same property ?

Bezout domains (which are not principal domains) is the term you're looking for

Thanks. With this term, it is easy to find the classical example of holomorphic functions on C.

DaRT query
